# Encapsulating an attribute

Tags: c#, .net, encapsulation, custom-attributes

I would like to know if it is possible encapsulate a c# attribute.

I explain better which is my goal:

I installed a package from nuget in a class library... In this package I have some attributes that I should use in different modules of my project... I do not want to install the package everywhere, so I want to create a my custom attribute that hide the attribute from nuget package.

The only one idea that I have is to create a custom attribute that inherit from nuget attibute but this make no sense. In this way I am not encapsulantig and I should install nuget package everywhere.

I try to do an example:

```
MyLibrary.csprj <-- Here I install nuget package
    |
    |--> MyCustomClassAttribute.cs 
    |--> MyCustomParamAttribute.cs
```

`MyCustomClassAttribute` and `MyCustomParamAttribute` are my custom attributes that should hide the nuget package attributes. One of the nuget package attribute is something like this:

```
public class NugetPackageAttribute : Attribute
{
    public NugetPackageAttribute(string inputParameter)
    {
    }
}
```

I do not need to pass an input paramet to my custom attribute because is a costant value to me.

Then I must use my custom attributes in different other modules of my project:

```
MyProjectModule1.csprj
  |
  -->MyProjectClass1.cs
```

`MyCustomClass.cs` is something like this:

```
[MyCustomClass]
public class MyProjectClass1
{
    public void DoWork([MyCustomParam]object param)
    { ... }
}
```

So, a way to encapsulate an attribute exists?

Thank you

**EDIT**

I try to find a general solution for a problem.
I have a solution with N projects.

```
Solution
    └-> Project 1
    └-> Project 2
    └-> Project 3
   ...
    └-> Project N
```

I must install a Nuget package that contains some attributes. I should use those attributes in different points of the solution. That means that I should install the nuget package in different project of my solution, for example:

```
Solution
    └-> Project 1 //<-- Nuget Package X here
    |     └-> [NuGetAttr]public void Class1{}
    |
    └-> Project 2 //<-- Nuget Package X here
    |      └-> [NuGetAttr]public void Class2{}
    |
    └-> Project 3
    |
   ...
    └-> Project N //<-- Nuget Package X here
          └-> [NuGetAttr]public void ClassN{}
```

I want to avoid to install everywhere the nuget package. So I want to do something like this:

```
Solution
    └-> Project 1 //<-- Reference to my Project N+1
    |     └-> [MyCustomAttr]public void Class1{}
    |
    └-> Project 2 //<-- Reference to my Project N+1
    |      └-> [MyCustomAttr]public void Class2{}
    |
    └-> Project 3 
    |
   ...
    └-> Project N //<-- Reference to my Project N+1
    |     └-> [MyCustomAttr]public void ClassN{}
    |
    └-> Project N+1 //<-- Nuget Package X here and stop
          └-> public void MyCustomAttr : Attribute {} //<-- Here inside use the NuGetAttr, or I dont know what...
```

Comment: `so I want to create a my custom attribute that hide the attribute from nuget package` please explain this.

Comment: you can create an assembly with the same name (and strong name if present, so signature) as the assembly containing the attribute and containing only the attribute definition. Then you reference this "reduced version" of the assembly.

Comment: What prevents you from defining an attribute with the same name directly in your code? `class FoobarAttribute : Attribute { }`

Comment: I have edited my post, I hope is clearer now.

Comment: How is this attribute used in your code? Are you just retrieving it via reflection? Or is the code in the Nuget package using it?

Comment: it is used in the code of the Nuget package

Comment: Then "I do not want to install the package" doesn't make much sense, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: perhaps I have not understood your question before. I edit my post again... give me 5 minutes please

Comment: Ok, I just meant what is the attribute used for in your code.

Comment: @Konamiman I have edited my post, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172215/discussion-between-konamiman-and-ciccio).